# Forgot password with firebase from login activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Looking at the documentation, I just found this:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String emailAddress = "user@example.com";

auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                }
            }
        });
```

I have a problem because I need to implement forgot password functionality in the login activity, where FirebaseAuth is null because user is not logged in, so how can I figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` method will never return `null`, so your code will work.

It's the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` method that will return `null` if the user is not logged in.

From the [Android Firebase Authentication getting started documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/):

> Declare an instance of `FirebaseAuth`
>
> ```
> private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
> ```
>
> In the `onCreate()` method, initialize the FirebaseAuth instance.
>
> ```
> mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
> ```
>
> When initializing your Activity, check to see if the user is currently
>   signed in.
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onStart() {
>     super.onStart();
>     // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
>     FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
>     updateUI(currentUser);
> }
> ```

And the code you have in your question is from the [send a password reset section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email):

> You can send a password reset email to a user with the
>   `sendPasswordResetEmail` method. For example:
>
> ```
> FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
> String emailAddress = "user@example.com";
>
> auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress)
>         .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
>             @Override
>             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
>                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>                     Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
>                 }
>             }
>         });
> ```

The `emailAddress` variable is specified here, because the user is not logged in.